# Find what values of 'b' have bounded solution(differential equation)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, periodic-functions

$y′′ + b^2{y} = f(t)$

$ f(t) = t$ for $0 < t < 2\pi$ ($2\pi$ periodic sawtooth wave)

This is my solution to the differential equation.
$y(t) = C_1\cos(bt) + C_2\sin(bt) + b^{-3}\left(bt - \sin(bt)\right) - 2\pi b^{-2}* \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (1 - \cos\left(bt - 2\pi an)\right)u(t - 2\pi n)$

$C_1$, $C_2$ are constants, $b$ is positive real number and $u$ is unit step function. I need to find for which values of $b$ does this equation above have a bounded solution. I have no idea how to solve this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see a differential equation here...

Comment: @TZakrevskiy I added differential equation. What I posted was my solution.

Comment: @Martin is `user152063` (the author of the post) the same person as you?

Comment: The form of the solution is far from being useful for the analysis. You should write it (assuming $b^2>0$) like $c_1 \sin (bx) +c_2 \cos (bx)+\frac 1b \sin (bt)\int_0^t\cos (bs)f(s)ds-\frac 1b\cos(bt)\int_0^t\sin(bs)f(s)ds$.